# Accessing contents of res/raw programmatically (Android)

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an app for Android with a few other people, and the primary content is specified by our designers as text files in a certain file format, which we then parse, process, and serve in the app.  We're currently storing them in `res/raw`.

This makes things great for the designers because when they want to add content, they simply add a file to `res/raw`.  This is annoying as a developer, however, since we developers then need to add `R.raw.the_new_file` to an array in the code specifying which files to process at startup.

Is there a way to access the resource ID's of `res/raw` programatically?  Ideally when the application starts, we could make a call to see which files are in `res/raw`, process all of them, so we could eliminate the small overhead with matching up the contents of  `res/raw` with that of our array in the code.

The most promising path I've seen is [`getAssets`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getAssets()) from [Resources](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html), which would let me call [`list(String)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html#list(java.lang.String)) on the [AssetManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html), but I've had trouble getting this to work, especially since you can't directly call `"res/raw"` as your filepath (or at least, it hasn't worked when I've tried.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use reflection.

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Field[] fields = R.raw.class.getFields();
for(Field f : fields)
try {
        list.add(f.getInt(null));
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) { }
```

After that list holds all resource IDs in the res/raw folder.
If you need the name of the resource... f.getName() returns it.

Comment: Thanks, late to accept but I'd forgotten that I hadn't.  Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 6):

This answer may be a bit late, you should use assets folder instead. There you can have a folder hierarchy and read it as a file system.

For your info the [getAssets](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getAssets%28%29) returns a manager for files in the "assets" folder of your Android project and not in "res/raw". "res/raw" goes into the "R" Java Package. [assets.list(path)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html#list%28java.lang.String%29) Returns an array of files in the given folder relative to your assets folder. The asset's folder is also not a traditional folder, but Android abstracts it so it "feels" like regular files. This becomes more important if you are doing JNI and want to read your assets from c/c++.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
Context.getResources().getIdentifier("filename", "raw", "packagename");
```

to get the appropriate identifier. however i don't understand why you implement your solution that complicated? what are the advantages for the designer? why they don't just put the files in drawable folder?

Comment: This is actually not for graphics, but for levels in a game.  Each level has a static map, a variable number of dynamic objects, locations for those objects, level-specific notifications, a number of configurations, etc.  Rather than have the level designers edit our codebase directly, we wrote a parser to allow them to specify the levels declaratively in text files; and we chose to put them in res/raw.

Thanks for the tip!  I'll give a try and let you know how it goes ^_^