# How to obtain name of the file present in Raw folder

Tags: android

I am working on a music player app where I play audio files present in Raw folder.

I have 2 files named abc.mp3 and def.mp3 in "raw" folder.

On Click of Button I play abc.mp3 and  click on other button I play def.mp3 
I need to display  the name of the file I'm playing on a TextView . 
When I click on button I need to display a message saying "Playing abc song" on another I need to display "playing  def song"
How do I get the name of the file present in "raw" folder.

Can anyone help in obtaining the name of mp3 files present in raw folder .

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to get all names of files in raw folder. Thanks to @Padde

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
Field[] fields = R.raw.class.getFields();
for(Field f : fields)
try {
    list.add(f.getName());
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) { 
    }
```

I have modified the answer of @Padde [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2805630/3884250)